# layout_weight doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-layout-weight

In my Application I have an Activity as in figure (figure #1).
In the TableLayout i would to build a table with n rows and 6 columns.
I build the table inserting, like a list, n LinearLayout and each of them contains 6 TextView (the values of table) and 5 TextView which act as spaces between columns.
I have written this, custom_linearlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/custom_linearLayout" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/titolo1"
        android:text="tit1"
        android:background="#4584d3"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/spazio1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/titolo2"
        android:text="tit2"
        android:background="#4584d3"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/spazio2"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/titolo3"
        android:text="tit3"
        android:background="#4584d3"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/spazio3"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/titolo4"
        android:text="tit4"
        android:background="#4584d3"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/spazio4"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/titolo5"
        android:text="tit5"
        android:background="#4584d3"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/spazio5"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/titolo6"
        android:text="tit6"
        android:background="#4584d3"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The rendering should be something like this: (figure #2)

This is the java code for using the Layout:

```
package blablabla.myapplication;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import blablabla.myapplication.R;

public class Riga extends LinearLayout {
    TextView colonna1, colonna2 , colonna3, colonna4, colonna5, colonna6;

    public Riga (Context contesto) {
        super (contesto);
        init ();
    }

    private void init () {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from (getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_linearlayout , null);
        colonna1 = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.titolo1);
        colonna2 = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.titolo2);
        colonna3 = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.titolo3);
        colonna4 = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.titolo4);
        colonna5 = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.titolo5);
        colonna6 = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.titolo6);
        addView(ll);
    }

    public void setVal1 (String s) {
        colonna1.setText(s);
    }

    public void setVal2 (String s) {
        colonna2.setText(s);
    }

    public void setVal3 (String s) {
        colonna3.setText(s);
    }

    public void setVal4 (String s) {
        colonna4.setText(s);
    }

    public void setVal5 (String s) {
        colonna5.setText(s);
    }

    public void setVal6 (String s) {
        colonna6.setText(s);
    }

    public void setValues (String [] array) {
        if (array.length == 6) {
            colonna1.setText(array[0]);
            colonna2.setText(array[1]);
            colonna3.setText(array[2]);
            colonna4.setText(array[3]);
            colonna5.setText(array[4]);
            colonna6.setText(array[5]);
        }
    }


    public void setBackgroundColor (int colore) {
        colonna1.setBackgroundColor(colore);
        colonna2.setBackgroundColor(colore);
        colonna3.setBackgroundColor(colore);
        colonna4.setBackgroundColor(colore);
        colonna5.setBackgroundColor(colore);
        colonna6.setBackgroundColor(colore);
    }

    public void setForegroundColor (int colore) {
        colonna1.setTextColor(colore);
        colonna2.setTextColor(colore);
        colonna3.setTextColor(colore);
        colonna4.setTextColor(colore);
        colonna5.setTextColor(colore);
        colonna6.setTextColor(colore);
    }
}
```

And inside the activity I call these instructions:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
Riga rigaTitoli = new Riga (this);
tl.addView(rigaTitoli);
```

But I have this (figure #3)

[image]

Where is the mistake? How can I fix?

Comment: image #2 is ur desired result?

Comment: Yes, it should be like that.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from (getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_linearlayout , null);
> ```

You're passing a `null` as the parent view which makes `match_parent` sizing for your inflated `LinearLayout` to not work. Consider passing `this` as the root, and remove the `addView()` since by default the inflater adds the inflated view to a non-null parent.

Comment: It works!!Thanks a lot!!
I have to set Solved to question?How can I do it?